# Arrays Merging Instead of Appending in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I'm attempting to append these two arrays as they're built but am getting unexpected results in Python:

```
This = []
That = []

This.append('A')
That.append(This)

This.append('B')
That.append(This)

print(That)
```

Expected results: [['A'],['A','B']]

Actual results: [['A','B'],['A','B']]

Whereas this works as expected:

```
That = []

This = ['A']
That.append(This)

This2 = ['A', 'B']
That.append(This2)

print(That)
```

Expected results: [['A'],['A','B']]

Actual results: [['A'],['A','B']]

Comment: You appended `This` twice, that's what you get in `That`.

Comment: Consider list names in python as "pointers" to the same list. Try a `print(This)`. This will reveal `This=['A','B']`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Comment: Unhelpful comment, Diego Torres Milano, I adjusted the post to show an example of why this would be unexpected behavior.

destructioneer - thank you for this, considering it like pointers is helpful in making sense out of what it's doing.

Comment: That link was helpful, Abdul Aziz Barkat, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to think of the "this" as just one object, if you want 2 different objects in you have to copy a copy of this like `That.append(This.copy())`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: Thank you for the response, Jonatan!  I selected Mukul Tripathi for the accepted answer due to the additional information about mutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises on line 7 of your code. When I am updating `This` array the second time with `This.append('B')`, it is automatically updated in `That` array.

Similar issue:

[Python list updating elements when appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690875/python-list-updating-elements-when-appending)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting unexpected results is because both This and That are referring to the same list object. When you append This to That, you're appending a reference to the same list object. So when you modify This, it reflects in both places where it's referenced.

To achieve the expected results, you need to make a copy of This when appending it to That, so that modifications to This don't affect the elements already appended to That.

```
This = []
That = []

This.append('A')
That.append(This.copy())

This.append('B')
That.append(This.copy())

print(That)
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, add `print` statement after each line and see the output. Explanation given

```
This = []
That = []

This.append('A')
print(This)  #Output : ['A'] 
#Now This has become ['A]


# appending This to that. (i.e) appending ['A'] to [] should give [['A']]
That.append(This)
print(That) # Output : [['A']]


# This is ['A']. If 'B' is appended, this becomes ['A', 'B']. But this is already inside that. that becomes [['A', 'B']]
This.append('B')
print(This) # Output : ['A', 'B']
print(That)

#Now  that is [['A', 'B']]. this is ['A', 'B']. appending this to that, that becomes [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B']]
That.append(This)
print(That)
```

So if at all you want to use the same object after appending but without change in appended list, create a copy of this

```
This = []
That = []
This.append('A')
That.append(This)
There = This.copy()
There.append('B')
That.append(There) 
print(That) #Output: [['A'], ['A', 'B']]
```